# Accessing IndexedDB of a Javascript Metro App in a Background Task

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, indexeddb

I am trying to access the indexeddb from my app (so I can update a live tile) in a javascript background task.

I am setting up the task like so:

```
        var builder = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.name = taskName;
        builder.taskEntryPoint = "js\\task\\backgroundTask.js";

        //Run every 8 hours if the device is on AC power
        var trigger = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.MaintenanceTrigger(480, false);
        builder.setTrigger(trigger);

        var task = builder.register();
```

The task looks like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var backgroundTaskInstance = Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIBackgroundTaskInstance.current;
    var cancel = false;

    function doWork() {
        var key = null, settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;

        //todo access db and update tile

        close();
    }

    if (!cancel) {
        doWork();
    } else {
        close();
    }

    function onCanceled(cancelSender, cancelReason) {
        cancel = true;
    }

    backgroundTaskInstance.addEventListener("canceled", onCanceled);

})();
```

The task seems to work fine but I can't work out if I can access the db (or any of the apps resources). Is this sort of thing even possible, if so what have I missed?

Comment: If you access the indexeddb API & try to write data, what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453270.aspx, the WorkerGlobalScope in a Store app, which is in effect when you're in a background task, makes indexedDB available. IndexedDB works within local appdata, so should be usable as any other appdata operations.

Generally speaking, background tasks can modify app data and issue tile/toast/badge updates. As Slace points out, you can't access other app resources, so appdata is how you share data with the main app.

Answer (score 0):

I think background tasks are run on different threads (so that they don't have the same toombstoning restrictions) and can't access application resources. This is how background tasks are kept alive even when the application is suspended, meaning that you can't access application resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IndexedDB API inside a worker, but you then you need to use the [sync API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#sync-database).

My experience with workers in Windows 8 development is that you can't use async API's inside it. When making async calls, the provided callbacks won't get called. Also as mentioned by Kraig only the API's accessible by the worker scope can be used. (you can't call anything from the window object.)